# Fetch row from tableview on Button click in same row JavaFX

Tags: button, javafx, tableview, row

I have created a TableView in JavaFX it contains two columns :

- First Row (Roll): It contains roll no. of student
- Second Row (Details): It contains a Button which when clicked prints "Roll" of corresponding row.

My Approach is:

```
    static ObservableList<Student> list= FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    static ObservableList<Student> getStudentList() throws SQLException {
        con = ConnectionUtil.getDataBaseConnection();

        String SQL = "Select * from student;";            
            ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);  
            while(rs.next()){
              //Student cm = new Student(rs.getInt("rno"), rs.getString("name"),false);
                Student cm = new Student();
                cm.setFullName(rs.getString("name"));
                cm.setRoll(rs.getString("rno"));
                cm.setSingle(false);
              list.add(cm); 
            } 
      return list;
    }
```

---

```
    static TableColumn<Student, String> rollCol = new TableColumn<Student, String>("Roll");

    static TableColumn<Student, Void> viewCol = new TableColumn<Student, Void>("Details");
```

---

```
      static TableColumn<Student, Void>  addButtonToTable() {
        //TableColumn<Student, Void> viewCol = new TableColumn("Button Column");

        Callback<TableColumn<Student, Void>, TableCell<Student, Void>> cellFactory = new Callback<TableColumn<Student, Void>, TableCell<Student, Void>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<Student, Void> call(final TableColumn<Student, Void> param) {
                final TableCell<Student, Void> cell = new TableCell<Student, Void>() {

                    private final Button btn = new Button("View");

                    {

                        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {

                            /////////////////WORK START FROM HERE
                            static Student stu=tables.getItems();

                            String res = (stu.getRollNo().toString());

                            System.out.println(res);
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (empty) {
                            setGraphic(null);
                        } else {
                            setGraphic(btn);
                        }
                    }
                };
                return cell;
            }
        };

        viewCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);

        return viewCol;
    }
    public String getRollNo() {
        return rollNo;
    }
    public void setRoll(String rollNo) {
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
    }
```

Problem with me:

- My Table shows both columns well
- But it doesn't prints the "Roll" in the output.

Please tell me how can I do this...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`static` is not allowed for declarations of local variables and `TableView.getItems` returns a `ObservableList`, not `Student`. Access the `Student` instance via the `TableRow`. (If you display all the buttons in a row, not in a column, the required logic would be very different.)

```
private final Button btn = new Button("View");

{

    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        Student stu = getTableRow().getItem();
        String res = stu.getRollNo().toString();
        System.out.println(res);
    });
}

@Override
public void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    setGraphic(empty ? null : btn);
}
```